# Transform a data frame into a spatial data frame to be able to get an ESRI shapefile to open in QGIS (R programming)

Tags: r, shapefile, qgis, spatial-data-frame

I have a data frame in R (no2df) it looks like this:

```
    **> head(no2df)
                  id     latb     lonb      lat      lon        no2tc
        5028741 816834 32.95808 36.61589 33.00045 36.63499 3.276456e-05
        5028742 816834 32.98067 36.67716 33.00045 36.63499 3.276456e-05
        5028743 816834 33.04274 36.65399 33.00045 36.63499 3.276456e-05
        5028744 816834 33.02014 36.59268 33.00045 36.63499 3.276456e-05
        5028745 816835 32.98067 36.67716 33.02291 36.69604 2.578415e-05
        5028746 816835 33.00300 36.73795 33.02291 36.69604 2.578415e-05**
```

As the above matrix suggests every four points (that have the same id) form a polygon (or in my case a pixel or cell), the bounds of the cell are shown under columns "latb" and "lonb" and the center of the cell is repeated four times under columns "lat" and "lon" because it is the same center for each cell. Finally, most importantly, I have the variable NO2 depicted under column "no2tc" it follows the same reasoning as the lat and lon.

The question is the following:

What should I do (please give the steps) to convert or manipulate this data frame into a spatial data frame so finally I am able to export to an ESRI shapefile that contains the cells with the variable "no2tc" as the cell attribute, so I can view in QGIS?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. This link is helpful in setting out a reproducible example [reprex] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: hi Peter, I honestly tried a lot of stuff and it is very messy I honestly do not know what to show, I am a civil engineer beginner in coding and I need help in this matter to use it for my thesis project only, kindly suggest what you have if you can, thank you a lot.

Comment: This reference  may provide  some guidance https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net. I'm sorry I do not have the answer otherwise I would have helped. I have been  asked to review questions and know from my experience of answering  that  a summary of back ground information checked out there and the code that  has been tried gives a better chance of a good answer.